# Continuity of quotient map

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that there is a natural homomorphism from a vector space X to X/Y  where Y is a closed subspace.
I want to show that this map is continuous but while using the definition of continuity I am a bit confused.
 Kindly help

Thnx n regards

Comment: Can I have a proof , how it's true.

Comment: The topology of $X/Y$ is defined by the condition that the natural homomorphism $\phi$ is continuous. The theorem is that $X/Y$ is Hausdorff iff $Y$ is closed.

Comment: From what I understand, the topology on the quotient space is defined such that the projection is continuous. Hence there is nothing to prove.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient map is defined in the way that it is continuous already.